# Changing hosts file in Mac OS X does not take effect

Tags: macos, mac, dns, hosts-file

I have tried to alter the hosts file adding my own entries to access sites that are being blocked by my ISP.

When address the entries as follows

```
194.71.107.82   totallylegalsite.se
```

After adding the line the changes do not take effect, I have tried in both Safari and Chrome browsers.
I have tried to flush the cache via `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` however this still does not make the system read the new lines. I have also tried rebooting the machine.

EDIT:
Strange scenario here, by pinging the IP address stated above I get the following output:

```
Ping has started…

PING 194.71.107.82 (194.71.107.82): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8

--- 194.71.107.82 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

However I visit the IP directly via my browser it works fine and loads the website it should.

Comment: When you `ping totallylegalsite.se`, what do you see?  Does the address `194.71.107.82` appear in ping's output?  Do the pings succeed?

Comment: It is quite likely that your ISP is not blocking DNS only, he might be blocking the access to the sites themselves. In this case, changing the hosts file will not help you at all.

Comment: @John1024 They do not succeed, please check revised post.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Well heres the thing, the direct IP actual works which leads me to believe it may just be DNS

Comment: @Imran That is helpful: the part that reads `PING 194.71.107.82` indicates that your `hosts` file entry worked correctly.  The problem, whatever it is, seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: @John1024 Sorry I have mentioned I tried to ping 194.71.107.82 directly and that was the result. I did this to see if I could even ping that address, which looks like I cant.

Comment: ICMP and TCP are different protocols.  Firewalls can block one and not the other, so a negative ping result should never be taken as a definitive indication of unreachability.